# First step issue in Worksheet_change calculation

Tags: excel, vba, onchange, worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Stavba, DataStavba, Kalkmix As Range
Set Stavba = Range("f9:f14")
Set DataStavba = Range("e5:e8")
Set Kalkmix = Range("i10:j11")

If Not Intersect(Target, DataStavba) Is Nothing And Range("F14") = "Error" Then
'Application.EnableEvents = False
 Debug.Print "Cells changed inside: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Application.EnableEvents = True
 Stavba.Calculate
 Else:
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Debug.Print "Cells changed outside: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
 End If


'If Intersect(Target, DataStavba) Is Nothing Then
'   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    'Debug.Print "Cells changed outside: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
    'End If


End Sub
```

The goal is when users are changing data in range DataStavba and F14 = Error (this indicates that values in DataStavba are not proper ones  for Kalkmix), then calculate only data in range Stavba and not in range Kalkmix (because is too complex calculation in that area). But in case of Else, calculate all cells in Sheet (including Kalmix)

Where is the issue? Working as I wanted except first step, i.e.Kalkmix is calculated on first step always after "switching" OK-Error or vice versa or changing cell outside DataStavba region.
As can be seen from above I have tried to have double IF, but it was not working properly either. The issue is that Client is putting wrong data into DataStavba (cell f14 is switched from OK to ERROR), but Kalkmix is still calculated - and a result can be the file closing. If another value is changed in DataStavba, Kalkmix is not calculated = desired scenario in first step too.
Print.Debug is always the right one.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for people to assist if you have some sample data.  You have `Stavba, DataStavba, Kalkmix` ranges, but its not clear which types of values or to be calculated, only their ranges.  Perhaps there is an issue with values.  Sample data would make it clearer.

Comment: When you say F14 = "Error" do you mean the value is a string, or do you mean boolean [IsError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function) ? If the cell value turns into #NAME? or #REF! when the data is incorrect then the IsError function is how you can check that.

Comment: Also, if the sheet is set to xlCalculationAutomatic then Worksheet_Change triggers after the sheet calculates. So by the time you say xlCalculationManual, it is too late, since the changes have already been calculated. What you probably want is to have the sheet always set to xlCalculationManual, and selectively call Sheet.Calculate by your own criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If the sheet is set to xlCalculationAutomatic then Worksheet_Change triggers after the sheet calculates. So by the time you say xlCalculationManual, it is too late, since the changes have already been calculated. What you probably want is to have the sheet always set to xlCalculationManual, and selectively call Sheet.Calculate by your own criteria.

I suggest the following:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_close()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Kalkmix As Range, EverythingExceptKalkmix As Range

    Set Kalkmix = Range("I10:J11")
    Set EverythingExceptKalkmix = Union(Range("A:H"), _
                                        Range("K:" & Split(Cells(1, Columns.Count).Address, "$")(1)), _
                                        Range("I1:J9"), _
                                        Range("I12:J" & Rows.Count) _
                                        )
    'Check if the data is good
    Range("F14").Calculate
    
    If Range("F14") = "Error" Then
        EverythingExceptKalkmix.Calculate
    Else
        'If its "OK" then calculate the whole sheet
        Me.Calculate
    End If

End Sub
```